# Searching an array recursively - CodingBat

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

*Apologies for the ambiguous title, I could not think of something more specific.*

In order to get better at solving problems recursively, I have been tackling the questions posted on [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1). My question is related to a variation of the following problem.

**The [original problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p173469) is:**

> Given an array of ints, compute recursively if the array contains
>   somewhere a value followed in the array by that value times 10. We'll
>   use the convention of considering only the part of the array that
>   begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass
>   index+1 to move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as
>   0.
>
> - array220({1, 2, 20}, 0) → true
> - array220({3, 30}, 0) → true
> - array220({3}, 0) → false

**My solution to this problem is:**

```
public boolean array220(int[] nums, int index) {
  if (index >= nums.length-1) return false;

  if (nums[index+1] == nums[index] * 10) return true; 

  return array220(nums, ++index);
}
```

However, in order to challenge myself, I was wondering how I would go about solving the following variation of this problem that I conceived:

> Given an array of ints, compute recursively **if the array contains
>   somewhere a value that is 10 times larger than any other value**. We'll use
>   the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins
>   at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass index+1 to
>   move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as 0.
>
> For example:
>
> - array220({**1**, 2, **10**}, 0) → true
> - array220({3, **2**, 9, 38, **20**}, 0) → true
> - array220({3}, 0) → false

So basically, the difference with the original problem is that the values may not necessarily be adjacent to one another (see examples above).

How would I go about doing this recursively? I would appreciate some pointers.

I do not want to change the method signature or use global variables.

Comment: This is not really a recursive problem, even in its first version. However, an iterative algorithm can always be converted in a tail-recursive algorithm, so you can just write your hastable solution in a recursive fashion

Comment: @Dici the problems posted on CodingBat are meant to be solved only using recursion. I am doing this for practice. How would I go about doing this recursively without using a data structure? It appears I need a way to do a nested loop.

Comment: Similar to how you do in original version, just add an additional Hash Table as a parameter in recursive method.

Comment: @sparrow the whole purpose of this activity is to practice recursion. The problems on CodingBat are designed to be solved without loops. Please read the problem carefully. Efficiency or elegance is not of relevance to this question.

Comment: @PhamTrung how would I go about doing this recursively without the use of additional data structures? Could you provide some pseudocode?

Comment: Hmm, without additional data structures, so the time complexity will increase.

Comment: @PhamTrung I am not concerned about time complexity.

Comment: @gentleArt: Did you try to modify your original solution to check the rest of the array instead of the single element at index+1? What exactly is the problem that prevents you from doing it?

Comment: Added a solution without additional data structure, the solution will have O(nlogn) time complexity.

Comment: @Dima I am not quite sure how to do a nested loop recursively.

Comment: @gentleArt, the way to do a nested loop is the same as to do any other loop. Like in PhamTrung's solution, `binarySearch` is the "nested loop". If you don't want to sort and binserach, you can make a `linearSearch` function to do the same thing linearly.

Comment: problem is best candidate for recursion if you can define of the problem in terms of smaller instances of itself. although i thought of the other solution to it but waste few minutes just thinking about for recursive solution before seeing answer and comments as i'm also practising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be the answer, just making use of a HashSet, and passing it along when you make recursive call:

```
public boolean array220(int[] nums,HashSet<Integer> set,  int index) {
  if (index >= nums.length-1) return false;

  if (set.contains(nums[index]*10)) 
      return true; 
  set.add(nums[index]);
  return array220(nums,set, ++index);
}
```

If you don't want to use additional data structures, sorting array and making use of binary search can bring you an O(nlogn) solution, with two recursive methods.

```
Arrays.sort(nums);

public boolean array220(int[] nums,  int index) {
  if (index >= nums.length-1) return false;

  if (binarySearch(index + 1, nums.length - 1,nums[index]*10,nums)) 
      return true; 

  return array220(nums, ++index);
}

public boolean binarySearch(int start, int end,int value, int[] nums){
     if(start > end)
        return false;
     int mid = (start + end)/2;
     if(nums[mid] == value){
         return true;
     }else if(nums[mid] > value){
         return binarySearch(start, mid - 1, value, nums);
     }else{
         return binarySearch(mid + 1, end, value, nums);
     } 
}
```

If you don't want to sort the array, using a linear recursive search will give a O(n^2) solution.

```
public boolean array220(int[] nums,  int index) {
  if (index >= nums.length-1) return false;

  if (linearSearch(0,nums[index]*10,nums)) 
      return true; 

  return array220(nums, ++index);
}

public boolean linearSearch(int start, int value, int[] nums){
     if(start >= nums.length)
        return false;

     if(nums[start] == value){
         return true;
     }else {
         return linearSearch(start + 1, value, nums);
     } 
}
```

Comment: How can we do it without the use of a data structure? I am not concerned about efficiency. I do not want to change the method signature or use any global variables.

Comment: @gentleArt, look at the second and third solution, the solution doesn't require additional datastructure

Comment: Could you clarify the following boolean condition: 

(nums[index] % 10 == 0 && linearSearch(0,nums[index]/10,nums)) 

I am not quite sure what this is doing? Is it checking for 0? 

Thank you!

Comment: @gentleArt `nums[index] % 10 == 0` means that whether the current `nums[index]` is divided by 10, for example: 10, 20, 30,... if it is, so we need to find 1, 2, 3..., which is `nums[index]/10`

Comment: @gentleArt hmm, that part is not necessary, just remove that part